# Why are my TF-IDF features per sample different for train and test inputs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

Tf -idf is givng value error it works fine before now its throwing eror

```
tf_idf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))
tf_train=tf_idf_vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
tf_test= tf_idf_vectorizer.transform(X_test)
model=LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_predict=model.predict(X_test)

ValueError: X has 97624 features per sample; expecting 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `model.fit(tf_train, y_train)`, then `model.predict(tf_test)`.

```py
tf_idf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))

tf_train=tf_idf_vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
tf_test= tf_idf_vectorizer.transform(X_test)

model=LogisticRegression()

model.fit(tf_train, y_train)

y_predict=model.predict(tf_test)
```

You `fit_tranform` the transformed inputs, i.e. `tf_train` and you apply the `model.predict` to also the transformed test inputs, i.e. `tf_test`.

---

As a sanity, check, do a `len(X_train)` and you should get 97624 then `len(X_test)` and you should get 11. There's where this error comes from:

> ValueError: X has 97624 features per sample; expecting 11

P/S: Take a careful look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html